# How can i get in array or List all the child gameobjects under a gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the top of the script:

```
public CameraControl cameraControl;
public Object birdPrefab;
public Transform birdParent;
private Transform cameraObj;
public Transform[] instancePoints;
public int _birdscount;
private Settings res;
```

Then in this function

```
private GameObject InstantiateBird( Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Boid.Settings boidSettings )
  {
    var obj = (GameObject)Instantiate( birdPrefab, position, rotation );
    var boid = obj.GetComponent<Boid>();

    obj.transform.parent = birdParent;
    boid.SettingsRef = boidSettings;
    boid.DebugSettingsRef = settings.debugSettings;

    return obj;
  }
```

And then in the function i want to get all the childs:

```
int prevBirdCount;
    IEnumerator _WatchBirdCount()
    {
        prevBirdCount = _birdscount;

        while(true)
        {
            if(_birdscount != prevBirdCount)
            {
                prevBirdCount = _birdscount;
                //Do something
                foreach (Transform child in birdPrefab)
                {
                    //child is your child transform
                }
                InstantiateBirds();
            }
            yield return 0; //Wait a frame before checking again
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

But the foreach is wrong: foreach (Transform child in birdPrefab)

This is a screenshot showing the hierarchy while the game is running and the inspector of the main camera on the right.

You can see in the Hierarchy under BirdsParent i want to get all the HumanBirdPrefab(Clone) in a List and then to do something with them.

In the inspector you can see in the Main (Script) the Bird Prefab and Bird Parent.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Judging from http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/594210/get-all-children-gameobjects.html , that foreach loop is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I could be wrong but in that foreach, you can't use the gameObject, you need to use a transform, so either do

```
foreach (Transform child in birdPrefab.transform){}
```

or if birdParent is the transform of the birdPrefab, do this

```
foreach (Transform child in birdParent){}
```

This error message is useful and should have been added to the question: Assets\Scripts\Main.cs(5,5): Error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'UnityEngine.Object' because 'UnityEngine.Object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' (CS1579) (Assembly-CSharp)

Comment: Right it was my mistake. Sorry. It should be birdParent not prefab.

Comment: It's a simple mistake to overlook :P Be sure to mark it as the answer if that fixes it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing in that `foreach`: there's just a comment, inside. You should add `child.gameObject` to the list at each iteration.

Comment: Side note: my suspect is that you copied the answer from here without understanding the logic, am I right?
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/205391/how-to-get-list-of-child-game-objects.html

Comment: I see. In fact, you should iterate over a Transform. Maybe birdParent is the one that you wanted to use?

Comment: Why is your `birdPrefab` of type `Object`? This should most likely be of type `GameObject` (I assume it is a prefab from your assets folder assigned in the inspector). Also, you can only use this foreach based of a transform and this should also be in the scene already (= instantiated), not being a prefab.